# How to stop Wndproc() loop?

Tags: c#, hotkeys, wndproc

I have overridden wndproc() to use Hotkeys. but the form won't close anymore. and onclosing form the program stuck in an infinite loop in wndproc().

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {


            Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);                  

            int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();                                        


            MessageBox.Show("Hotkey has been pressed!");
            // do something
        }

    }
```

i have set the e.cancel to true and added following codes in the OnFoemClosing method  `

```
 e.Cancel = false;
 base.OnFormClosing(e);
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: The message box is probably the key to all your woes

Comment: Have you tried set the KeyPreview property = true and manage keyPress event instead to tweak the WndProc?

Comment: the problem with the Keypreiew is that the associated  from must be open to work.if the form is minimized or not selected it not work. but i need a hotkey that works with interrupts service routines.

Comment: What you set to e.Cancel ever?

Comment: In the body of OnClosingForm method i have set 'e.Cancel=false'

Answer (score -1):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

//Closes the form
btnCloseWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DestroyWindow(this.Handle);
}`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

//Closes the form
btnCloseWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DestroyWindow(this.Handle);
}`
```